# jQuery multiple form repeater

Tags: html, jquery

I am using a form repeater but my goal is to have multiple repeaters to use it on my project. I tried to search on different forums but I didn't get positive result to follow. my current code only repeats for the first div only i.e. `targetDiv` one and doesn't repeat for the second div

I want to repeat all divs `targetDiv`

jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/infohassan/qbontgj6/2/

**Here is my HTML**

```
<div class="row targetDiv" id="div0">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="myRepeatingFields" class="fvrduplicate">
                <div class="row entry">
                    <!-- Field Start -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Length(mm)</label>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Length">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Field Ends -->

                    <!-- Field Start -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Qty(pcs)</label>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Qty">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Field Ends -->

                    <!-- Field Start -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-add">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Field Ends -->
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row targetDiv" id="div1">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="myRepeatingFields" class="fvrduplicate">
                <div class="row entry">
                    <!-- Field Start -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Length(mm)</label>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Length">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Field Ends -->

                    <!-- Field Start -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Qty(pcs)</label>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Qty">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Field Ends -->

                    <!-- Field Start -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-add">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Field Ends -->
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Here is my JS**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var controlForm = $('.fvrduplicate:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);
        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
            .html('<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: its hard for me I want to follow the same code

Comment: Please elaborate more .

Comment: @Swati please check the updated one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked your code a little bit, maybe this is what you want?

- I made the `id` attributes in your `.fvrduplicate`-divs unique ("group1" and "group2")
- the `controlForm` is now *not* taken from the first `.frvduplicate` div but from the `.closest()` one to the clicked button
- the rest is mostly unchanged, however, I added the "+" and the "-" for the buttons (as the css classes `fa-minus` and `fa-plus` are curently undefined in this snippet) and separated the two forms with an `<hr>`-element.

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var controlForm = $(this).closest('.fvrduplicate'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);
        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
            .html('<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true">-</i>');
    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('.entry').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row targetDiv" id="div0">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="group1" class="fvrduplicate">
      <div class="row entry">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Length(mm)</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Length">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Qty(pcs)</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Qty">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-add">
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">+</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>  <!-- second form starts below: -->
<div class="row targetDiv" id="div1">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="group2" class="fvrduplicate">
      <div class="row entry">
        <!-- Field Start -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Length(mm)</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Length">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Qty(pcs)</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Qty">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-add">
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">+</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked perfect you're the man of Jquery :)